# How to parse podupti.me´s json via Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

How can I parse this [json](http://podupti.me/api.php?key=4r45tg&format=json) via Gson?

Here is my [PodModel.class](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1530380/)

And [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1530398/) is my for retrieve the json.

This is the gson part.

```
    gson = new Gson();
    PodsModel pods = gson.fromJson(builder.toString(), PodsModel.class);
    System.out.println(pods.getPods().getDomain());
```

Logcat returns with this: [logcat-output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1530392/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that `Gson` failed here:

```
"pods":[{"id":
       ^
```

This `[` is unexpected because in your model `PodModel` `pods` field is plain field, not an array.

May be you have to change `pods` to by an array, and in this case you will be able to parse such `json`.

**UPD:** Just change `pods` definition to this one:

`private List<ItemPod> pods;`

- change according way getter and setter.

This solution should work (tested).